# TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined when testing solidity contract

Tags: solidity, truffle

I have a problem like this. I am building a dapp using Ethereum while following a video tutorial.

This is my smart contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract SimpleWallet {
    address owner;
    mapping(address => bool) isAllowedToSendsFundsMapping;

    event deposit(address _sender, uint amount);
    event  withdraw(address _sender, uint amount, address _benificiary);

    function SimpleWallet()public{
        owner= msg.sender;
    }

    function (){
        if(msg.sender == owner || isAllowedToSendsFundsMapping[msg.sender]== true){
            deposit(msg.sender, msg.value);
        }else{
            throw;
        }
    }

    function sendFunds(uint amount, address receiver) returns (uint){
        if(msg.sender == owner || isAllowedToSendsFundsMapping[msg.sender]){
            if(this.balance>= amount){
                if(!receiver.send(amount)){
                    throw;
                }
                withdraw(msg.sender, amount, receiver);
                return this.balance;
            }
        }
    }

    function allowAddressToSendMoney(address _address){
        if(msg.sender == owner){
            isAllowedToSendsFundsMapping[_address]=true;
        }
    }

    function disallowAddressToSendMoney(address _address){
        if(msg.sender == owner){
            isAllowedToSendsFundsMapping[_address]=false;
        }
    }

    function isAllowedToSend(address _address) constant returns (bool){
        return isAllowedToSendsFundsMapping[_address]|| msg.sender == owner;
    }

    function killWallet(){
        if(msg.sender == owner){
            selfdestruct(owner);
        }
    }


}
```

Here I am providing the testing file.

```
var SimpleWallet = artifacts.require('./SimpleWallet.sol')
contract('SimpleWallet', function (accounts) {
  it('the owner is allowed to send funds', function () {
    var myContract = SimpleWallet.deployed()
    return myContract.isAllowedToSend.call(accounts[0]).then(function (isAllowed) {
      assert.equals(isAllowed, true, 'the owner should have been allowed to send funds')
    })
  })
})
```

But when I hit truffle test in the console it gives me an error like this.

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

I recheck the code with the video but both codes are similar. It working correctly in the video but in my computer, it is not working correctly. And I google it but i was not able to find a suitable answer to my problem. can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank You.

Comment: On which line it does happen? Probably configuration issue.

Comment: Can you share the link to the video tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed and simplified your test file, here you go:

```
const SIMPLE_WALLET = artifacts.require('SimpleWallet.sol');

contract('SimpleWallet', function (accounts) {

  let simpleWallet;

  beforeEach('setup contract for each test case', async () => {
    simpleWallet = await SIMPLE_WALLET.new({from: accounts[0]})
  })

  it('should let owner to send funds', async () => {
    const isAllowed = await simpleWallet.isAllowedToSend(accounts[0]);
    assert(isAllowed);
  })
})
```